# Why do we use retarded Green's functions in response theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body, greens-functions

When computing the response of a system to an external perturbation, we usually use the retarded Green's function to describe the response. On the other hand, from scattering theory in Quantum Mechanics, the perturbation series is given in terms of time-ordered Green's functions. If I would use time-ordered perturbation theory to calculate the response of my system, I would probably get a very different answer. How do I know which one I need to use?

For example, if I'm shining a laser on my material, is that scattering or is that more like equilibrium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Response of a system is usually described by a retarded Green's function, which reflects the causality (response follows the perturbation, rathe rthan preceeds it). Indeed an approximate evolution of an operator, under Hamiltonian $H=H_0 + V(t)$ is described by:
$$
\langle A_H(t)\rangle=\langle S^\dagger(t)A_I(t)S(t)\rangle\approx \langle A_I(t)\rangle - \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^tdt_1\langle\left[A_I(t), V_I(t_1)\right]\rangle =\\
\langle A_I(t)\rangle - \frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt_1\langle\left[A_I(t), V_I(t_1)\right]\rangle\theta(t-t_1),\\
S(t)=T\exp\left[-\frac{i}{\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^tdt_1V_I(t_1) \right],
$$
where $A_H(t)$ and $A_I(t)$ are the operators in Heisenberg and the interaction representations. The retarded Green's functions is manifest in the second line.

The problem is that calculation of the retarded function is usually rather cumbersome, whereas for time-ordered Green's functions one may obtain nice closed expressions (e.g., the very intutive ones represented by the Feynmann diagrams). One therefore usually calculates the time-ordered Green's function and then passes to the retarded Green's function using Lehmann representation.

This logic is taken one step further in Keldysh formalism, where one calculates contour-ordered Green's function, which has time-ordered components alongside the retarded and advanced ones.

Detailed discussion of calculating retarded response function from a time-ordered one can be found in discussions of Kubo formula or dielectric response in most many-body texts, such as Fetter&Walecka or Mahan (AGD has it all too, but in rather cryptic form).

Comment: Thank you! I see that the retarded Green's function is manifest in the second line, but why did you take the expectation value of the operator A in the first line? Is that always what is being measured? Shouldn't it depend on the experimental setup?

Comment: One always measures an expectation value, not the operator itself. The experimental setup determines which operator is measured - e.g., in Kubo formula we are measuring current in response to applied bias/potential/EM field. Also, one has to be careful what one averages in respect to - on most cases it would be just thermodynamical average, but there are some special sitiations (e.g., when dealing with superconductivity).

Comment: Ok. I would think that we are sometimes interested in scattering amplitudes, and not necessarily the average properties of the material.

Comment: Perhaps, we are talking about different things - I am looking at it from the point of view of solid state physics, where one usually interested in response of the material, rather than in the apmlitudes of particular processes (as in QFT).

Comment: Still, I would expect the two to be the same at lowest order in perturbation theory. Is that not true?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *scattering amplitudes* - amplitudes are not measurable in QM, but we can measure scattering probabilities (amplitudes squared). In Solid state these have to be further averaged over the occupied initial states, and vacant final states (at least, often the intermediate state are also important) - because the things are not happening in vacuum, as in QFT.

Comment: Yes, I mean probabilities. So we average over initial states, and final states, but we don't average over intermediate states, so it seems the response function at intermediate times should be different.

Comment: If you use thermal Green's functions (Matsubara formalism) you automatically average over all the necessary states - initial, final, and intermediate. Also in zero temperature formalism, although this can be reformulated as vacuum formalism.

Comment: But what I'm saying is that if you're considering scattering, maybe average over the intermediate states is not a good thing to do.

Comment: It is not exactly averaging - an electron cannot go into a filled state (below the Fermi level), whereas a hole cannot go above the Fermi level. Anyhow, all these are taken care of by the Green's function formalism.

Comment: Ok i'll take a look at the references you cited.